# Sensenet : 'Node is out of date Id' while calling user.save()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sensenet

I have trying update field of User and update it on sensenet database server by below code

```
string strNow = "abc";
var currentUser = (User)User.Current;
currentUser = User.Load("domainname", currentUser.FullName);
currentUser.SetProperty("ExtensionData", strNow);
currentUser.Save();
```

I am getting error 'Node is out of date Id:XXXXX' in some cases.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually "Node is out of date" exception in an environment where many things may happen at the same time is not a real error. It just means that in the meantime somebody (or a background thread) modified the same content. You can **reload** the node and try the operation again. There is a simple [retrier API](https://github.com/SenseNet/sn-tools) in sensenet for that:

```
Retrier.Retry(3, 10, typeof(NodeIsOutOfDateException), () =>
{
   // execute something that may throw a NodeIsOutOfDateException
   var currentUser = Node.Load(User.Current.Id);
   currentUser["ExtensionData"] = strNow;
   currentUser.Save();
});
```

Reloading the node is a good practice in this case because User.Current is something that may be a pinned object in the background, accessible by multiple threads.

> Please also note that it is usually better to use the indexer for accessing properties instead of the Get/SetProperty methods that are meant to be used internally. Or if there is a dedicated property on the business object (like user.FullName), please use that.

Comment: Toth still it is not working, it is trying three times and on third time it is throwing same exception